# Excel Countifs function keeps returning "0" value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: output "# in Title" that returns an error of "0"]
**output "# in Title" that returns an error of "0"**

[image: where data is coming from]
**where data is coming from**

I am trying to see how many departments contain a given title code (a 4 digit code assigned to each job title).  There is 1 spreadsheet that contains all the data, and the formula I'm using keeps returning a value of "0", although that is inaccurate.  I'm not sure if it is because the departments are written in text and the title codes are numbers, but I've been unable to get a formula to match what I'm trying to get.

I have this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(copyempdata!AN2:AN33004,Recommendation!C17,copyempdata!AO2:AO33004,Recommendation!A17)
```

In this formula:

- 'copyempdata' - where data is stored
- 'Recommendation' - referencing points and where I'd like the output
- 'C17' - departments
- 'A17' - title codes

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look to the data.  There may be spaces or other unprintable characters that make it look like they are the same but Excel sees them as different.

Comment: Also it does matter, `"1" <> 1`

Comment: Thanks but I've tried that with no results - went through and was unable to find any spaces or additional characters.  Formula is still returning a value of 0

Comment: The problem is your data, and as such we can only guess.

Comment: That's not helpful

Comment: try supplying 3-4 rows of example data

Comment: Are you sure those two happen on the same row in the lookup table?  I do not see it in what you have provided.

Comment: You're right, the lookup table (2nd pic) only shows a few of the values, but both of them go down to ~33,000.  I'll do a screenshot of the first visible data so it's more.

Comment: in order to have code 0313, one of two things is happening.  Either 0313 is actually text, and probably so since it is left justified.  However that could be left justification applied to the cell and the cell is formatted to display leading zero and is actually a number.  If you do =ISTEXT(C17)  on the first sheet do you get true?  What if you do =ISTEXT(Q2)? What is the format of the cell where you are getting 0?  is it set to general?

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(clean(trim(copyempdata!AN2:AN33004)),clean(trim(Recommendation!C17)),clean(TRIM(copyempdata!AO2:AO33004)),clean(trim(Recommendation!A17)))
```

The CLEAN and TRIM function do similar jobs but are different.  Basically they should eliminate special characters and excess spaces as Scott was suggesting in his comments.

Comment: Appreciate the formula but did not change results - tried using the clean and trim function to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I've feeling that you want do something *simpler*, using 2 times the function `COUNTIF()` (not `COUNTIFS()`):

```
=COUNTIF(copyempdata!AN2:AN33004,Recommendation!$C$17) + 
 COUNTIF(copyempdata!AO2:AO33004,Recommendation!$A$17)
```